# Get properties for a site from an other module in Maven

Tags: maven, markdown, velocity

Considering we have a project with the following modules:

```
project/
    project-module-1/
    project-module-2/
    project-docs/
        src/site/
            markdown/
                index.md.vm
            site.xml
```

Now I want to read properties from `project-module-1 and 2` in the `index.md.vm` from the `project-docs` module.

**index.md.vm**

```
${module1.project.name} 
${module1.project.version}
${module1.project.description}

${module2.project.name} 
${module2.project.version}
${module2.project.description}
```

How can I do this? I can't find anything about this in the Maven or Markdown Documentation.

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 1):

Define the properties in the top level aggregator pom and use them in all three projects as desired. And the top level pom has to be used as the parent in all of them so the values can be inherited.